# Hide dependent DLL functions

Tags: c, dll, sqlite, cvi

I am struggling to understand if I can prevent exposing certain function calls from within a DLL that I am building.  The function calls I want to hide are calls that are exposed by sqlite3.dll which I am building into another DLL of my own making.  sqlite3.dll exposes 5 functions, one of which looks like this in the header:

```c
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_close(sqlite3*);
```

The macros at play here are defined earlier as:

```
/*
** Provide the ability to override linkage features of the interface.
*/
#ifndef SQLITE_EXTERN
# define SQLITE_EXTERN extern
#endif
#ifndef SQLITE_API
# define SQLITE_API
#endif
#ifndef SQLITE_CDECL
# define SQLITE_CDECL
#endif
#ifndef SQLITE_STDCALL
# define SQLITE_STDCALL
#endif
```

Now, I am building sqlite3.dll into my application by linking against sqlite3.lib and including sqlite3.h (the source of the prior code snippets).

I realize I may be able to play with those macros to achieve what I want.

I expose the functions in my own dll with:

```
/* module entry point */
int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall load_properties(CAObjHandle context);
```

When I look at the functions available in the output of my build, I get my functions+5 functions from the sqlite library.  All of the functions in sqlite that are exposed have the declaration structure similar to what I showed for close() above.

Is there a way I can hide the sqlite functions?  Is it the .lib file that is causing the issue?  That file was auto-generated so I am not sure what is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer.  The sqlite3.dll was incorrectly specified as a source of exports to the compiler.  Removing the directive to export functions from sqlite3.dll corrected the issue.